# Looking for a cordova plugin to add speech recognition to cordova app (supporting iOS13+, Android 10+, Windows UWP)

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, speech-recognition

i am looking for a good cordova plugin to add speech recognition to my cordova app. 
I need to support at least iOS 13+ and Android 10+.
Can anyone recommend a well working plugin?
I tested: https://github.com/pbakondy/cordova-plugin-speechrecognition but this was quite instable, hard to integration and no feedback to tickets since 1 year :-)

Do you know of any good ressources for speech recognittion APIs per se.?

Best regards
Hannes

Comment: That plugin is a wrapper for the native speech recognition API from the device, instead of looking for an alternative, I'd try to improve that one or fix its glitches by creating a fork.